# powermail errormessages in german

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Hi I've got a problem with Powermail.

I want that the Errormessages are in german. I read that i have to configure the config in typoscript:

I tried this:

```
locale_all = de_CH.utf8
index_enable = 1
 sys_language_uid = 0
 language = de
```

but nothing happens.

Can anybody help me how to configure this correctly, that it works in german.

Thank you

Comment: Did you import the german language pack via the extension manager (4.x) or the language module (6.x)?

Comment: Who says that the error messages are available in german for every extension ;) I cant find a german translation in the default TER plugin, only english and danish:)? Maby you have to translate it yourself frist?

Answer (score 0):

I think your locale is wrong.

It has to be

```
de_CH.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a wrong locale_all setting.

If you are using a Linux-Server, type

> locale

in your console.
Search the output for a variable named LANG, e. g.

> LANG=de_CH.UTF-8

This is what you have to use as locale_all in TYPO3 (without "LANG=").